# How is "libs" created and maintained in a gradle android project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I currently am not using the ["libs" folder](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationProjects) for my third party dependencies (it seems they are added automatically to build/intermediates/pre-dexed/) but noticed that it may help static code analysis so I would like to add it to the project.
**Note: I'm using maven dependencies**.

My question: Are people using custom scripts to generate this folder? I hardly think that this is generated once and then manually maintained when there is a newer version available.

Please enlighten me!

Comment: It depends if are local jars or maven dependencies

Comment: In this case maven dependencies, I will clarify the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Android Studio AND Gradle, there is **no need** to use libs folder (except for old .jar library).

In fact you can **develop Android app whitout Android Studio** as in your build.gradle there is already a `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Gralde is using Maven or jCenter via gradle dependencies to import libraries. Gradle and Android Gradle plugin will **automaticly download** the libs as you sayed in a build/ folder. It is not static and can be clean with the `Clean projet` on Android Studio. Also, Android Studio will add a warning when a new library version is available automaticly in your build.gradle.

Dont miss the old `libs` folder used to import .jar library

Comment: But even without Android Studio, when I compile using command line it works fine with the dependencies without the libs folder.

Comment: and it's totaly normal @Alix your build.gradle `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: Exactly. So "Android Studio" is not really necessary for this to work then? Or do you mean that other IDEs don't work properly without it?

Comment: Android studio manage gradle state (I maybe don't understand everything), other IDE will be able to manage Android with gradle I think. So you can develop Android app in Sublime text I guess.

Comment: Okay, I can accept your answer but it's incorrect to say that Android Studio is needed, the mechanisms are somehow already in place to cope without the libs folder

Comment: If you look in dependencies you will see the default option to search the libs folder for jar files. That is why that happens. As Hugo says, the libs folder isn't strictly necessary anymore. Only for .jar files that aren't available by the usual Gradle dependency system.

Answer (score 0):

> I currently am not using the "libs" folder for my third party dependencies (it seems they are added automatically to build/intermediates/pre-dexed/) but noticed that it may help static code analysis so I would like to add it to the project. Note: I'm using maven dependencies.

Don't confuse the `libs` folder with `build/intermediates/pre-dexed/` folder.
Currently the **gradle plugin for Android** manages the build process and create these "internal" and intermediates folders.

> My question: Are people using custom scripts to generate this folder?
>   I hardly think that this is generated once

You don't have to create this folder. The Gradle plugin for Android manage it for your. Also it will be deleted and recreated when your run a `gradlew clean` command.

> and then manually maintained when there is a newer version available.

No. Your dependencies are defined in your `build.gradle` file.
When you define a new version, Gradle downloads the new dependency and updates the intermediate folders.

You can define your dependencies in many ways:

```
dependencies{
   //You can create a folder and put jar files inside. You can use your favorite name, usually it is libs.
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

   //The support libraries dependencies are in a local maven managed by SDK 
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

  // A Maven dependency
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

  //A local library
  compile project(':mylibrary')

  //An aar file. It requires to define a repository.
  //repositories{
  //    flatDir{
  //            dirs 'libs'
  //     }
  //}
  compile(name:'nameOfYourAARFileWithoutExtension', ext:'aar')
}
```