# Proper configuration for "sonar.libraries" in a modern Gradle Android project

Tags: android, sonarqube, android-gradle-plugin

**What I want to achieve:**

In sonar it is possible to track third party dependencies used throughout Projects by setting the property "sonar.libraries" and perhaps there are more benefits (such as detecting which violations are caused by external libraries?)

**What I tried to do:**

I set the value to `build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/*.jar` but this seems to have little effect.

**Question:**

[Since it is no longer needed to use the "libs" folder for third party dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327031/how-is-libs-created-and-maintained-in-a-gradle-android-project/), what is the recommendation for the property called "sonar.libraries"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to implement special processing when an Android project is detected. Correctly setting sonar.java.libraries is one of the requirements. A ticket already exists, feel free to vote or provide a pull request.
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-6

Update: we have released version 2.1 of the plugin ([currently RC2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/ZLaC2ickLSM)) that natively supports Android projects. Properties `sonar.java.[test.]binaries` and `sonar.java.[test.]libraries` will be automatically populated.

Comment: Great! What about the property `sonar.java.test.binaries` and `sonar.java.version`?

Comment: @Alix They are also supported, I'll update my answer.

Comment: So no need to specify sonar.java.version anymore?

Comment: Should be also correctly provided for Android projets with 2.1.

Comment: Provided by the plugin you mean? Not provided as a parameter in the config file?

Comment: @julien-h-sonarsource-team

If omitting to explicitly set "sonar.java.version" I see issues such as squid:S1609 which are only applicable on Java 8 codebases even though I target version API level 19 (which is not compatible with Java8 syntax).

I can see this behavior for sonarqube gradle plugin 2.1-rc2

Comment: @Alix I was not aware of this relationship between API level and Java source version. I will have a look. Please continue discussion on the ticket SONARGRADL-6

Answer (score 1):

The pre-dex folder also seemed to me to be the perfect candidate. Unfortunately, if you look into the jars in this folder, you'll see they contain no compiled class, but dex files. A dex file being a "dalvik executable", it's Android material, and Sonar can't do anything of it.

I managed to reference **some** of my dependencies, by declaring `build/intermediates/exploded-aar/**/*.jar` in the `sonar.libraries` property.

With this line you'll see all the "android librairies" (aar) that your project depends on. I've not yet managed to track all the other plain java libraires (jar)

Comment: aar files should have a classes.jar at the root level, nothing should be dexed.

Comment: @bmg : dude, just read the question and the answer before reminding us that an aar contains a .jar and a res/ folder ;)

Comment: Lol my bad; an alternative could be to extract all aar dependencies and add the extracted jar files to `sonar.java.libraries` property.

Comment: Native support of aar in classpath was added in Java analyzer 4.2: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1652